# How to create wordpress function?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, function

i need to create function in word press function file to print some HTML cord. i tried this function.

```
function pre($chord){

echo '<pre>$chord</pre>'

}
```

and i use it in my post like this

```
<?php pre("sd");?>
```

and it will not work. please help me.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a WordPress problem, it's basic PHP. Try to replace the apostrophes in your function with double quotes and note that if you are showing HTML code you might want to use http://php.net/htmlentities

Comment: You forgot a `;` after the `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

You are building your string incorrectly. when mixing html and php strings you need to concatenate the data like so...

```
function pre( $chord ) {
    echo '<pre>' . $chord . '</pre>';
}
```

Also bear in mind that Wordpress is a large and modular CMS so by naming your function something as simple as `pre` you run the risk of conflicting with some other function called `pre`. It's good practise to prefix your functions with a unique string of letters like so...

```
function abc_pre( $chord ) {
    echo '<pre>' . $chord . '</pre>';
}
```

Use whatever works for you.

Dan

Comment: Adding to what Dan said, you will probably want to register a shortcode, so you can use your function in WordPress pages and posts, as PHP code is normally not allowed there and stripped out.

Have a look at the [Shortcode API.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)